# Backlight blinking in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I don't know how exactly to put this question. But the case is like:
                 In main page of app, I have four panorama pages. First page contains longlist selector,second contains ten rectangles grouped in group of two with help of horizontal and vertical stack panels and scrollviewer. Third page again has a text box and longlistselector(search functionality). Fourth page has just three buttons. 
                 I have also five storyboard animations, four for two longlistselectors(two for each- one for fadeIn,second for fadeout). All four storyboard animations are data triggered. One storyboard animation contains a composite transform and a renderTransformOrigin animation that collectively flips rectangle in 3D-space along its Y axis.

So this was about layout. I have other pages in the app too having longlistselector but this problem of blinking backlight is only coming in the main page. Every time I navigate to other ages from main page( by selecting longlistselector item or one of rectangles), backlight flickers/blinks both when navigating from and navigating back to page.

If someone needs XAML layout, I will put that. For now if anyone have any idea, what might be happening, that would be a great help to me. This issue wasn't from start in the app

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean the backlight is blinking (turning on/off?)? Does this happen on more than one physical device?

Comment: Yes, for a second or less... backlit text and controls goes on/off. That gives like flicker effect. Unfortunately I don't have other device to test. This issue is not there in the emulator. Another thing is like I have one other page in the app having longlistselector,but no flickering issue is there.

Comment: Seems like a hardware issue? If you remove some storyboards, etc. does the problem still occur?